# how to convert stored procedure result as xml and to use it as sub node in another proc result

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a stored procedure named as

```
usp_Employee_GetInfo
```

this proc returns a table after execution.
like below:

```
Id Name DeptID
1  AAA  10
```

I want create a new procedure which returns xml after execution.
And it includes the above proc result as one sub node like below:

```
<company Name="XXX">
 <Emp>
   <Id>1</Id>
   <Name>AAA</Name>
   <DeptID>10</DeptID>
 </Emp>
</company>
<company Name="YYY">
 <Emp>
   <Id>2</Id>
   <Name>BBB</Name>
   <DeptID>20</DeptID>
 </Emp>
</company>
```

Can u guys suggest the best way to use existing proc to get the required output.
Thank u.

Comment: Is there a reason to use a Stored **Procedure**? If this SP is just reading and returning a table this was much better be done as *inline TVF*. In this case it was easy to write something like `SELECT * FROM dbo.MyFunction() FOR XML AUTO`.

Comment: Actually the data what i mentioned above is dummy data.
And the original data which returns from the proc is from multiple tables
and there are many scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare table variable. Put SP results in this table and create XML you need:

```
DECLARE @emp TABLE (
    Id int,
    [Name] nvarchar(max),
    DeptID int,
    company nvarchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO @emp 
EXEC usp_Employee_GetInfo

--F.e. output of SP is:
--Id    Name    DeptID  company
--1     AAA     10      XXX
--2     BBB     20      YYY 

SELECT  company as 'company/@name',
        emp.Id as 'Emp/id',
        emp.[Name] as 'Emp/Name',
        emp.DeptID as 'Emp/DeptID'
FROM @emp
FOR XML PATH('')
```

Will output:

```
<company name="XXX" />
<Emp>
  <id>1</id>
  <Name>AAA</Name>
  <DeptID>10</DeptID>
</Emp>
<company name="YYY" />
<Emp>
  <id>2</id>
  <Name>BBB</Name>
  <DeptID>20</DeptID>
</Emp>
```